# All my upgrades crash due to unsigned kernels

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, kernel, secure-boot

The problem I have is that all Ubuntu's proposed software updates end with a fail message, which tells me that the problem are unsigned kernels, so I don't know whether any of the updates succeed or not.

I have have upgraded from `16.04` --> `18.04`

Also I am using Kernel 4.20, which I have installed via `Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility`

Can anybody help so solve this problem?

Comment: Either sign the files or disable Secure Boot.

Comment: I think its a bug in 18.04: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1788727